# Java File to Binary Conversion

Tags: java, file, binary, io

How can i convert File to Binary? I just need it for my project. I need to encrypt a file by its binaries.

Comment: Files are already binary data. Please give more information.

Comment: What do you mean by convert a File to binary exactly?

Comment: if you mean file to byte array: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/file2bytearray.html

Comment: I need to make a program the can encrypt any types of file. Based on our proposal we are going to encrypt file by its binary.

Comment: Then see my post. It's what you want. Also discard any of the String stuff... It's now irrelevant.

Comment: File to its file binary equivalent. I select file using FileChooser and I need to convert the selected file to binary. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're referring to accessing the ACTUAL BINARY form then read in the file and convert every byte to a binary representation...

EDIT:

Here's some code to convert a byte into a string with the bits:

```
String getBits(byte b)
{
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        result += (b & (1 << i)) == 0 ? "0" : "1";
    return result;
}
```

If you're referring to accessing the bytes in the file then simply use the following code (you can use this for the first case as well):

```
File file = new File("filename.bin");
byte[] fileData = new byte[file.length()];
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
in.read(fileData):
in.close();
// now fileData contains the bytes of the file
```

To use these two pieces of code you can now loop over every byte and create a String object (8X larger than the original file size!!) with the bits:

```
String content = "";
for(byte b : fileData)
    content += getBits(b);
// content now contains your bits.
```

Comment: Do you think I can reverse it. binary representation to file.

Answer (score 1):

```
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            File file = new File("C:/log.txt");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ) );
            try {
                while( true ) {
                    sb.append( Integer.toBinaryString( input.readByte() ) );
                }
            } catch( EOFException eof ) {
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        } catch( FileNotFoundException e2 ) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: For xml just change to log.xml

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanatory code to encode / decode :

To Encode:

```
// Encode Character | char
Integer.toBinaryString(myByte);
```

```
// Encode Byte | byte
Integer.toBinaryString(myCharacter);
```

To decode :

```
// Use BigInteger insted of Integer beacause it can decode large binary code(2)
new BigInteger(data, 2).toByteArray()
```

Encode file :

```
private static void encodeToBinary(File inputPath, File outputPath) throws IOException {

        // Read all the bytes from the input file

        InputStream inputData = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream fileData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inputData.transferTo(fileData);

        // StringJoiner to store binary code(2) encoded

        StringJoiner binaryData = new StringJoiner(" ");

        // Convert every byte into binaryString

        for(Byte data : fileData.toByteArray()) {
            binaryData.add(Integer.toBinaryString(data));
        }

        // (File)OutputStream for writing binary code(2)

        OutputStream outputData = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
        outputData.write(binaryData.toString().getBytes());

        // [IMPORTANT] Close all the streams

        fileData.close();
        outputData.close();
        inputData.close();
    }
```

Decode file :

```
private static void decodeToFile(File inputPath, File outputPath) throws IOException {
        // -->>Just reverse the process

        // Read all the bytes from the input (binary code(2)) file to string

        InputStream inputData = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream fileData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inputData.transferTo(fileData);

        // ByteArrayOutputStream to store bytes decoded

        ByteArrayOutputStream originalBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Convert every binary code(2) to original byte(s)

        for(String data : new String(fileData.toByteArray()).split(" ")) {
            originalBytes.write(new BigInteger(data, 2).toByteArray());
        }

        // (File)OutputStream for writing decoded bytes

        OutputStream outputData = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
        outputData.write(originalBytes.toByteArray());

        // [IMPORTANT] Close all the streams

        inputData.close();
        fileData.close();
        originalBytes.close();
        outputData.close();
    }
```

Comment: You can't use `Integer.toBinaryString` as its output is of variable length (broken really), so you wouldn't know how to decode it

Answer (score 0):

With [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) you can obtain the bytes from a File

From JavaDoc:

> A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file
>   system.  What files are available depends on the host environment.
>
> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as
>   image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using
>   FileReader.