# Read any file as a binary string

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles

As the title suggests, is there any way to read a binary representation of a given file (.txt, .docx, .exe, etc...) in Java (or any other language)?

In java, I know how to read the content of a file as is, i.e:

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But I'm not sure (if it's possible) to read a binary representation of the file itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java File to Binary Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119141/java-file-to-binary-conversion)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119141/java-file-to-binary-conversion

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to read a file as a byte array?  Do you want to read the file as a String consisting entirely of '0' and '1' characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File(filePath);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)));
dataInputStream.readFully(bytes);           
dataInputStream.close();
```

`bytes` is a byte array with all of the data of the file in it

Comment: Or, just use [Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-).