# How do you convert a file to binary to be stored in a mySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm attempting to code a Java program. Right now I'm in the process of trying to convert a file (could be any extension, mostly would be word docs and powerpoint presentations) to binary to be stored in a mySQL database, but not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java File to Binary Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119141/java-file-to-binary-conversion)

Comment: Generally speaking, storing binary objects in the database isn't highly recommended, it can degrade the performance of the database and blow out the size. Generally, you store a reference to the file within the local context instead

Comment: "convert a file to binary", files are already binary...